# Amend validation message and style. Where is this tooltip being loaded from?

Tags: django

I've been trying to determine where this validation/error message and styling is coming from but I can't narrow it down?  I've reduced the template to a basic template so that it isn't loading base.html any longer but the tooltip still appears somehow.
However the tooltip and message don't appear in safari - it just defaults to the standard django email validation message "Enter a valid email address".
Note I have selected don't use `disable cache` in chrome dev tools (network) but that didn't help.

[image]

Form:

```
class EmailTestForm(forms.Form):
    email = forms.EmailField()
```

View:

```
class EmailTestFormView(FormView):
    form_class = EmailTestForm
    template_name = "site/test_email.html"
    success_url = "/signup"

    def form_valid(self, form):
        print('form is good')
```

Template:

```
{% block inner %}

<form action="" method="post" >{% csrf_token %}
{% crispy form %}
    <input  id="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-cta-primary" type="submit"/>

</form>

{% endblock inner %}
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^signup/$', views.signup_view, name="signup"),

    url(r'^emailtest/$', views.EmailTestFormView.as_view(), name="email_test"),
]
```

Comment: The tooltip is coming [from Chrome itself](http://www.tekphile.com/2011/10/disabling-chromes-obnoxious-html5-form-validation/).

Comment: Thanks - wow that's annoying - no wonder I couldn't find it.  A little bit more detail here confirming the style and error message is from chrome: https://plus.google.com/+PaulIrish/posts/FSTom28PryG

Comment: You can disable it by putting `novalidate` in your HTML form tag.

Comment: Alasdair, Daniel thanks for your answers both helped.  If you put it in as answer I will accept so it can more easily help others. Thanks.